# Absolute position is putting some margin on top

Tags: html, css

From my understanding, an absolutely positioned element should be wherever it should be as it would normally if no top or left was specified (aside from it doesn't occupy "layout" space). But in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y6J5/) it seems as it is having margin-top:10px; set.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>default position</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="position: absolute;">absolute position</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

div
{
    border: red 1px dotted;
}
td
{
    border: green 1px solid;
}
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Don't put `<div>`'s inside of `<table>`'s and then see how it goes.  `<table>`'s are not for making the layout.

Comment: @Sparky672, the question is intended for me to understand how CSS position works better

Comment: Yes I know, and by removing the `table`, it also reveals the answer.

Comment: Actually the keyword to the link to the spec you provided is this: "cause the **top** of the outer box to be positioned with respect to its containing block". I was thinking of the div as a whole when in fact, only its top edge is being respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple.  As per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html), the `absolute` positioned element is [outside of the document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position) and it's [also placed *"with respect to its containing block"*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos).  So therefore, without specifying the position, it's top/left corner is placed in the center of the `td` cell.

[This example uses `top` and `left` to move it](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y6J5/6/).

Answer (score 2):

The default valign for td-elements is center, and therefore the absolutely positioned element will be vertically aligned to the center. Since it's positioned by default by the top-left corner it will be placed with the top-left corner in the vertical center of its container.

Try setting valign="top" on the td-element containing the absolutely positioned element and you will see the "margin" disappears.

Comment: After adding some more divs on the left side, I guess what really happens is, it's trying to place the right side div's top left at the middle of the TD.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why it adds that extra margin but an easy way to fix it is to just set a position for it, like `top: 0px;` or `top: 10px;`.

Comment: It looks like the question is about the Why this is happening, not how to solve it.

Comment: I know and thats why I said I don't know why it adds the extra margin, I do happen to know a very simple fix if it's something s/he needs fixed right away :)

Comment: If you didn't know the answer, then you shouldn't post an answer.